# Char pointer in array is not freeing

Tags: c, string, pointers, free

I have an array of char pointers. This array have strings. When I want to free the allocated memory for one of the strings it works, but the string after the removed one turns into rubbish. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 3
void AddName(char *Names[],int *size)
{
    char str[100];
    int len;
    if (*size < MAX)
    {
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        scanf(" %s", str);
        len = strlen(str);
        Names[*size] = (char *)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(Names[*size],str);
        *size = *size+1;
    }
    else printf("Full Memory!!\n");
}
void RemoveName(char *Names[],int *size)
{
    int loc;
    if (*size > 0)
    {
    printf("Starting from 0. Enter the name's location: ");
    scanf(" %d", &loc);
    free(Names[loc]);
    *size = *size-1;
    }else printf("ERROR\n");
}
void PrintNames(char *Names[],int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf(" %s\t", Names[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
main()
{
    char *Names[MAX];
    int size = 0;
    int c;
    do
    {
        printf("=========================\n");
        printf("1- Add a new name.\n");
        printf("2- Delete an old name.\n");
        printf("3- Print names.\n");
        printf("4- Exit.\n");
        printf("=========================\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%i", &c);
        printf("=========================\n");
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1: AddName(Names,&size);
            break;
            case 2: RemoveName(Names,&size);
            break;
            case 3: PrintNames(Names,size);
            break;
            case 4: printf("Good bye.\n");
            break;
            default: printf("ERROR: Bad input.\n");
        }
    }while(c != 4);
}
```

If I print the names in the array, it gives `Carl Hello`. If I try to print again after freeing Carl it gives `↨Y` (it should print Hello).

Comment: Would it be possible to post a small self-contained snippet of code that actually compiles and exhibits the error you are asking about?

Comment: Your code does not compile. Enable all warnings, and fix them.

Comment: If it were "done", I would be able to copy, paste, and compile it, unless your question is about why it won't compile. I'm ok with which headers to include, but where is `MAX` declared, why doesn't `main()` have a return value?

Comment: @DavidO Sorry. Now you can copy the code and compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the main problem identified by RADAR in their answer, there are several other issues:

1. Here:

   ```
   Names[*size] = (char *)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
   ```

   don't cast the return from `malloc()`, and `sizeof(char)` is always one, so this should be:

   ```
   Names[*size] = malloc(len + 1);
   ```
2. You should check the return from `malloc()`, because it can fail and return `NULL`.
3. Here, as well as other places:

   ```
   printf("Enter a string: ");
   scanf(" %s", str);
   ```

   You can get a problem because the thing you're sending to `printf()` does not end with a newline. Interactive input and output is line-buffered by default in C, and on some systems you won't see that prompt until *after* you've entered your input. To avoid this, call `fflush(stdout)` if you want to make sure some output that does not end with a newline displays immediately.
4. `main()` returns an `int`, and if you don't want to use command line arguments, the proper declaration is `int main(void)`. While `main()` is the one function returning a value where you don't *have* to explicitly return one, it's better form if you do.
5. This:

   ```
   scanf(" %s", str);
   ```

   will lead to Bad Times if the user enters more than 100 characters. You can cope with this with `scanf()` but using `fgets()` is better.
6. In general, this type of input strategy using `scanf()` is fragile, particularly if the user enters the wrong thing. Particularly if you're getting a lot of input, you'll do yourself a big favor by defining some convenience functions to get lines and integers using `fgets()`, and re-using those functions.
7. Your formatting is pretty bad in some spots.

Here's a modified version taking all of the above into account:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 3
#define BUFFER_LEN 100

/*  Convenience function to get a line from
 *  standard input - caller must free         */

char * get_line(void)
{
    char str[BUFFER_LEN];
    char * newstr;
    int len;

    /*  Get line of input  */

    if ( !fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Couldn't get string!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*  Remove trailing newline, if present  */

    len = strlen(str);
    if ( len > 0 && str[len - 1] == '\n' ) {
        str[--len] = 0;
    }

    /*  Allocate memory and copy string  */

    if ( !(newstr = malloc(len + 1)) ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(newstr, str);

    return newstr;
}

/*  Convenience function to get an integer from standard input  */

long get_long(void)
{
    char * str, *endptr;
    long n;

    str = get_line();
    n = strtol(str, &endptr, 0);
    if ( *endptr ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: You didn't enter an integer!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    free(str);

    return n;
}

/*  Adds a name to a list  */

void AddName(char * Names[], int * size)
{
    if ( *size < MAX ) {
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        fflush(stdout);

        Names[*size] = get_line();
        *size += 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR: List full!\n");
    }
}

/*  Removes a name from the list  */

void RemoveName(char * Names[], int * size)
{
    if ( *size > 0 ) {
        int i;
        long loc;

        printf("Starting from 0, enter the name's location: ");
        fflush(stdout);

        /*  Free the desired name...  */

        loc = get_long();
        free(Names[loc]);

        /*  ...and move any names ahead of it back.  */

        for ( i = loc + 1; i < *size; ++i ) {
            Names[i - 1] = Names[i];
        }

        *size -= 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR: list empty!.\n");
    }
}

/*  Prints the names in the list  */

void PrintNames(char * Names[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
        printf(" %s\t", Names[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

/*  Main function  */

int main(void)
{
    char * Names[MAX];
    int size = 0;
    long c;

    do {
        printf("=========================\n");
        printf("1- Add a new name.\n");
        printf("2- Delete an old name.\n");
        printf("3- Print names.\n");
        printf("4- Exit.\n");
        printf("=========================\n");

        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        c = get_long();

        printf("=========================\n");

        switch( c ) {
            case 1:
                AddName(Names, &size);
                break;

            case 2:
                RemoveName(Names, &size);
                break;

            case 3: 
                PrintNames(Names, size);
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("Good bye.\n");
                break;

            default:
                printf("ERROR: Bad input.\n");
                break;
        }
    } while ( c != 4 );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input is Carl and Hello

Names[0] = Carl

Names[1] = Hello

Now you freed up the memory for Names[0]

When you print names, you are trying to print Names[0] which is already freed up, so you are getting garbage.

You need to move all the pointers to fill up the empty space

In this case on deletion of Names[0], you have only one entry so Have Names[0] point to memory at Names[1]

When you delete entry at i
you need to adjust the pointers like below till the end of the list.

```
Names[i] -> Names[i+1]
```